# When calling a embedded Python module, has the thread been switched?

Tags: python, c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a C program where I'm calling an embedded Python module on a Linux machine using:

```
Py_Initialize();

    PyObject_CallFunction(PyFun)

Py_Finalize();
```

My question is: will the python function still be running in the same thread as the C function? How do I check this?

I was using `thread.get_ident()` in python and `pthread_self()` in C to print the thread ID. But I'm not sure whether they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried printing pthread_self() from a wrapped C function during the execution of Python module. 
  1. It's identical to pthread_self() call before calling python model.
  2. two pthread_self() are not equal to thread.get_ident() in python.

So I guess
  1. in a same thread.
  2. pthread_self() and thread.get_ident() are quite different.